# Caching doesn't work when I use Kotlin Functional Types instead of Java Functional Interface for consuming messages from Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-function

According to this article https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/11/kotlin-support-in-spring-cloud-function , the support for Kotlin Functional Types has been added to Spring Cloud Function. It means that Spring Cloud Function can now recognize Kotlin functional types that effectively match to one of Java’s Supplier, Function or Consumer and treat them as such. So, for example we can use `Consumer<String>` and `(String) -> Unit` interchangeable. But it seems that I can not use Kotlin functional types if I want to use the cache mechanism.

Here is an example of my application (source code: https://github.com/grolegor/kotlin-function-type-for-spring-cloud-function):

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application {
    @Bean
    fun embeddedKafkaBroker(): EmbeddedKafkaBroker = EmbeddedKafkaBroker(1).kafkaPorts(9092)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

Here, I created a bean with Embedded Kafka Broker just for making this application reproducible. In the real world, I use a separate Kafka Cluster.

`ConsumerService` reads from Kafka using Kotlin Functions and uses `cachedSevice` for handling:

```
@Service
class ConsumerService(
    private val cachedService: CachedService
) {

    fun receive(event: String) {
        cachedService.cachedMethod()
    }

    // use Kotlin Functional Types instead of Java's Consumer Interface
    @Bean
    fun consumer(): (String) -> Unit = ::receive
}
```

`CachedService` has only one method which is cacheable. This method prints 'cache miss' if this method has been invoked. So, if caching mechanism works correctly we will see only one such message even if we call this function several times.

```
@Service
@EnableCaching
class CachedService {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = ["cache"])
    fun cachedMethod(): String {
        println("cache miss")
        return "answer"
    }

}
```

And, finally, we have a simple controller which depends on `cachedService` as well as `ConsumerService`:

```
@RestController
class Controller(
    private val cachedService: CachedService
) {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun get() =
        cachedService.cachedMethod()
}
```

Dependencies:

- **Spring Boot 2.6.1**
- **Kotlin 1.6.0**
- **Spring Cloud Stream Kafka 3.1.3**

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-function-type-for-spring-cloud-function</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kotlin-function-type-for-spring-cloud-function</name>
    <description>kotlin-function-type-for-spring-cloud-function</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.0</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run this application I see the following message in the output:

```
@Bean method KotlinLambdaToFunctionAutoConfiguration.kotlinToFunctionTransformerOld is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
Bean 'cachedService' of type [com.example.kotlinfunctiontypeforspringcloudfunction.CachedService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Bean 'consumerService' of type [com.example.kotlinfunctiontypeforspringcloudfunction.ConsumerService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

**It means that I can not use proxying mechanism such as @Cacheable.**
So, if I invoke my method using rest controller several times using this curl

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/'
```

I will have `cachedMethod` invoked several times.

**But if I create consumer bean using Functional Interface `Consumer` in `ConsumerService` like this:**

```
@Bean
fun consumer(): Consumer<String> = Consumer(::receive)
```

**Everything is correct!**

I don't see any messages about auto proxing and `@Cacheable` works as expected. So, if I run curl several times the method `cachedMethod` will be invoked only once.

Comment: A bit curious, but what is the relevance to spring-cloud-function and/or Kotlin here? I mean, you are using a function indeed (Consumer) and call your service from it. To spring-cloud-function it is just another bean, so cached or not we wouldn't know one way or the other at spring-cloud-function level. . . what am I missing?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky This bean is based on another service that is used for handling events, so the consumer invokes cached service and everything is fine, but when I use kotlin functional type instead of Consumer Functional Interface '@Cacheable' stops working because it became "not eligible for auto-proxying".

Comment: I am still not fully following. Can you please provide a small prototype that reproduces the issue and push it to github so we can take a look

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I've already provided a reproducible example that is not so small, unfortunately, but I don't know how to make it smaller. I provided a link to a repo with my example. If you run this code you will see when you use Kotlin functional type instead of Consumer Interface you will have messages in the log about the impossibility to make a proxy for beans, so because of that '@Cacheable' doesn't work (as well as '@Transactional' because Spring creates a proxy for such beans).

Comment: For me, it seems that this behavior is a bug.

Comment: Where is your example? Please include GitHub link

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky I've already included the link
https://github.com/grolegor/kotlin-function-type-for-spring-cloud-function

Comment: I provided a link in my question when I posted this question, so, this link is in my post.

Comment: My bad, sorry, missed it. Will take a look

Comment: Hey, sorry, just read your last Message `. . .about the impossibility to make a proxy for beans. . .`. There was actually a bug opened about this I believe - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/780. It's already fixed and is available either in the current snapshot of spring-cloud-function (3.2.2-SNAPSHOT) or in spring-cloud-function 3.1.6 which was released few days ago. Can you please give it a shot and let me know? Once again sorry for not reading your post more carefully

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky thanks for your answer, Oleg! I noticed some strange behavior. I tried both 3.1.6 and 3.2.2-SNAPSHOT versions and everything is the same... I get the same messages about auto-proxying while starting the application. But 3.2.1 version works fine in my case! Here is my example with 3.2.2-SNAPSHOT version of spring cloud function - https://github.com/grolegor/kotlin-function-type-for-spring-cloud-function/tree/3.2.2-version

Answer (score 0):

The fix is indeed in 3.2.2-SNAPSHIT but it is also in 3.1.6, so please update your dependencies to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure `spring-cloud-function-context` is 3.1.6 and also update Spring Boot top 2.4.13